# possibility to display only names before ":" and hide everything behind it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a txt file with the following structure:

```
Johan:6279f03c18e1665d451d93c66bd1eaad  
Annita:6279f03c18e1665d451d93c66bd1eaad     
Rudy:6279f03c18e1665d451d93c66bd1eaad   
Bert:ethrt74efgdg7jcnjsdnvfn53254   
Gerdy:6279f03c18e1665d451d93c66bd1eaad  
Barbara:kfdnjkgnf34346353dfrferytyh 
Gil:6279f03c18e1665d451d93c66bd1eaad
```

It contains `username:password` MD5hashed

i created a script to delete each line (each user) by admin.

```
<table>
    <?php
$delete = @$_GET['delete'];
$textFile = file("../userpwd.txt");
$lines = count($textFile);

if($delete != "" && $delete >! $lines || $delete === '0') {
    $textFile[$delete] = "";
    $fileUpdate = fopen("../userpwd.txt", "wb");
    for($a=0; $a<$lines; $a++) {
           fwrite($fileUpdate, $textFile[$a]);
    }
    fclose($fileUpdate);

   echo"<p class='alert'>Gebruiker verwijderd!</p><meta HTTP-EQUIV='REFRESH' content='1; url=deleteusers.php'>";

   exit;
}

foreach($textFile as $key => $val) {
$pre= "<tr><td>";
$line = @$line . $pre . $val . "</td><td><a style='float:right;' href =?delete=$key><img src='../images/delete.gif'></a></td></tr>";
}
echo $line;
?></table>
```

Now the table has a button right next to each txt line, to remove the user. But i want only he username to be displayed and everything behind the ":" not. Is that possible with this code?

thx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

split the value at `:` and show only the first part

```
foreach($textFile as $key => $val) {
    $pre   = "<tr><td>";
    $value = array_shift( explode( ':', $val ) );

    $line = @$line . $pre . $value . "</td><td><a style='float:right;' href =?delete=$key><img src='../images/delete.gif'></a></td></tr>";
}
```